# How do I login to phpmyadmin on Google Cloud

Tags: google-app-engine, phpmyadmin

I setup the Wordpress 1 Click, and Google Cloud, automatically created a user for me. I did not get any place, where the phpmyadmin password is. How can I get hold of that

Answer (score 19):

First off, when you deploy the one-click installation, you need to ensure you have 'install phpMyAdmin' checked - we will assume that was installed and you did not overwrite the phpMyAdmin default user & password after :)

Next, navigate to the Google Cloud Console and find your project where your WordPress installation is located. From the left side menu, open Compute Engine and on the VM instances tab, select your virtual machine.

Once you open that view, scroll down to the custom metadata section and find the 'MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD' value. That is the password you need to log into phpMyAdmin.

After you know that value, navigate to the external IP of your machine and add /phpmyadmin after the IP (e.g. xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/phpmyadmin).

The default user will be 'root' and then enter the corresponding value from MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD in custom metadata. That should do the trick and get you access into phpMyAdmin. Hope that helps!

Cheers,

Tyler