# Google Cloud WordPress MySQL password change

Tags: mysql, wordpress, google-cloud-platform

I have just managed to get a WP instance up and running on a Google Cloud VM. All is good and it is running WP fine. I have managed to update the 'temporary' passwords as advised for root MySQL user and phpMyAdmin user.

However it also recommends updating the password for the MySQL wordpress user. I am not sure how to do this and can't find much useful info.

Help please.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you can change the passwords in the phpMyAdmin interfaces.
[This stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38358958/how-do-i-login-to-phpmyadmin-on-google-cloud) Talks about how to access the pypMyAdmin interface.

Copied below for posterity:

> First off, when you deploy the one-click installation, you need to ensure you have 'install phpMyAdmin' checked - we will assume that was installed and you did not overwrite the phpMyAdmin default user & password after :)
>
> Next, navigate to the Google Cloud Console and find your project where your WordPress installation is located. From the left side menu, open Compute Engine and on the VM instances tab, select your virtual machine.
>
> Once you open that view, scroll down to the custom metadata section
> and find the 'MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD' value. That is the password you
> need to log into phpMyAdmin.
>
> After you know that value, navigate to the external IP of your machine
> and add /phpmyadmin after the IP (e.g. xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/phpmyadmin).
>
> The default user will be 'root' and then enter the corresponding value
> from MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD in custom metadata. That should do the trick
> and get you access into phpMyAdmin.

Once logged into phpMyAdmin, [This post](https://synoguide.com/2014/02/20/change-password-sql-database-phpmyadmin/) talks about navigating to the Users table and updating the password on the user record. They do note that if you're changing the root user's password:

> At this point, your wordpress site will not be able to access the contents of the database until you have updated the password on your wp-config file. Let’s do that...

But it sounds like you have root taken care of so this might not be an issue.

Comment: OK thanks guys. It seems that WP uses the root MySQL account so I wasn't sure why a 'wordpress' user is also created. I'll have a bit more of a dig around.